# Crash releasing image created by UIImage:resizableImageWithCapInsets

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, retain

I just started with iOS programming recently, and assumed that I understood Objective-C reference counting, but seems I didn't... The following code runs completely but makes my app crash afterwards with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` (code 1 or code 2).

**I am not using ARC (PhoneGap-based project).**

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    UIImage *a = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationBarBackButtonBlack.png"];
    UIImage *b = [a resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 13, 0, 7)];
    NSLog(@"a has %d retains, b has %d retains, a==b == %d\n", [a retainCount], [b retainCount], a==b ? 1 : 0);
    [a release];
    [b release];
    NSLog(@"#%d\n", i);
}
NSLog(@"FINISHED\n");
```

Output is as I'd expect:

```
a has 1 retains, b has 1 retains, a==b == 0
#0
a has 1 retains, b has 1 retains, a==b == 0
#1
a has 1 retains, b has 1 retains, a==b == 0
[...snip...]
a has 1 retains, b has 1 retains, a==b == 0
#9
FINISHED
```

What's the problem here? Is there some autorelease going on, or does the capped image keep a reference to the original? No idea.

Comment: retainCount is entirely useless. Don't call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imageNamed` and `resizableImageWithCapInsets` both return autoreleased objects. You should not release them manually.

In other words: if you did not `alloc`, `copy` or `retain` it, you should not `release` it!

And as a last hint: forget about the `retainCount` property, it is useless for you.

Comment: Makes sense now :) Is there a way of debugging such problems if autorelease was used on an object?

Comment: Just remember this thing that you have to call release only if you called alloc, retain, copy or mutableCopy on an object. Whenever you call any of these reference count goes up. Since you didn't call any of these methods on your objects a and b you don't need to release that object

Comment: don't forget `new` and `mutableCopy`

Answer (score 2):

you should not release image a and b.
Those images are auto released. you should only perform release of your objects when you use the keyword `alloc` or `new`.

Here is a fairly good primer to Memory management in Objective C:

http://interfacelab.com/objective-c-memory-management-for-lazy-people/